# How to set a crystal report datafile location in VB

Tags: vb6

How to set a crystal report datafile location in VB

CODE:

```
CR.DataFiles(0) = " & databasetext.Text & "
CR.ReportFileName = App.Path & "\rpt_attendancereport.rpt"
```

" & databasetext.Text & " - am selecting the database location

But it showing error "Unable to open database"

and also i checked  in crystal report ->> Database ->> Set Location ->> showing different location, is not showing my selected location

If am selecting a location it will appear in crystal report set location. How to make a code.

Need Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `databasetext` is a text field containing the path to the database? If that's the case your code is wrong. Try this:

```
CR.DataFiles(0) = databasetext.Text
```